# iOS to iOS device connection through streams (over IP-Address)

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, network-programming, video-streaming

As a final school-graduation project I try to develop a kind of spying-car. Which means there is an iPhone placed on a little LEGO-car and an iPad used as a "steering wheel" for the car. Also it is planned to transmit Audio and Video from the iPhone's microphone/camera to the iPad (more than the steering data vice versa).
In the first place the connection from iOS to iOS should be established over a local WiFi network and later - if possible - over 3G (by using the iOS devices network-IP and a DNS server to deal with frequently changing addresses).

My question is: which technology do you recommend using? I read about GameKit, peer-to-peer and so on, but I think these technologies are too abstract for later being able to communicate over 3G. I guess I need to go a little deeper into the low levels of the communication progress. Any suggestion that could bring me a step forward is highly appreciated! (also regarding other parts of my project)

One more thing: Some user suggested using a third party service and to route the sent (video) data over an external server. If possible, I'd rather not use any "middle man". It should just be a basic server-client communication where the iPad is the server and the iPhone the client.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of an open ended question, but interesting.

First of all, GameKit do have 3g p2p support, see here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html

It will handle the peer-to-peer addressing and establisment of the socket. It can also handle voice chat, but I personally never tried this feature so I can't say if it is feasible in your case.

One idea is to leverage existing video-chat services. This will give you a low-latency audio/video channel with peer-to-peer addressing (well, likely using a central server).

Apple's FaceTime is such a service, but there is no public API to it (AFAIK). Same goes for Skype and Google.

There are some paid services that look like they have nice iOS APIs:

- http://tokbox.com/platform
- http://docs.weemo.com/sdk/ios/

You have to figure out a way to transmit control commands to the peer iPhone, I did not see if the services above had any possibility of sending text messages/arbitrary data.

Tokbox has a free trial so you could try it out and see if it works for you.

I would go for GameKit if this is a hobby project on a budget and there is time for hacking, and probably look into a more high-level API if there is a deadline...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll definitely look into your mentioned solutions. However, I'd prefer not to use an extra server. I thought the iPad should act as the server and the car-iPhone as the client. Furthermore I need to keep the price as low as possible... (and I love solving things by myself without using too many third-party services :P)

Comment: You need *some* kind of server to set up communication (addressing), unless you are within the same WiFi network or within bluetooth coverage. A simple/cheap solution is to use Game Center as the server.

Comment: Isn't the communication over 3G the same concept as over WiFi? (to every device connect to a mobile internet is given its own IP address, no?)

Comment: On WiFi you can discover your peers automagically, without a central server. This is done by, for example, [mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (Bonjour).

Comment: Well, I'll just type in the servers (iPad) IP on the iPhone which is then going to connect to the typed IP. So I don't need any automatic peer detection. (That's easy on WiFi because IP addresses don't change too often but will be harder over 3G where they change with every reconnect)

Answer (score 1):

sorry for writing this as an answer, but i don't have enough rep to comment...
i'm working on a similar project and i currently don't have any advice regrading video-streaming, however, from what i read (extensively) i came to the conclusion that i need to use p2p connection between devices for better performance and use socket programming in order to achieve this (although not the most easy to implement choice).
I considered using **GameKit which i think will probably answer most of your needs as Krumelur pointed out**. but in my case, eventually the app will be cross platform so i had to use low level network programming. you can check out my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126405/how-to-establish-a-p2p-connection-between-the-iphone-and-the-simulator) to see the sources i used to try and make the connection between 2 peers, hopefully you'll have better luck than me...

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Currently I'm playing around with TCP (very useful GIT repo here: https://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper). Let's see what I can do with it :-)