# how to establish a p2p connection between the iphone and the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, c, p2p

I want to stream data between two peers. so i thought i'll start with just trying to send a simple string message between the two (or even just check if i can establish a connection between the two). i'm using my iphone and the simulator.
eventually the app will have to work cross platform (android/ios) so i'm using POSIX C networking APIs which will work cross platform as i read in the documentation.
I compiled the code from my own code and other sources such as SO, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html), [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) and [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html).
From what i gathered, each peer has be able to act as a server or client, 
so for the server part what i have so far is this code:

```
-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_len = sizeof(sin);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(21360);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "94.21.53.41", &(sin.sin_addr)) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error while converting IP");
    }
    if ((self.serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
         NSLog(@"socket retrieve success");
    }
    if (bind(self.serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error while binding");
    }
    len = sizeof(sin);
    if (getsockname(self.serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) < 0) {
        // Handle error here
    }
    int socket_port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);
    if (listen(self.serverSocket, 5) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error while listening");
    }
    NSThread *acceptConnectionThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self      selector:@selector(startAcceptingConnections) object:nil];

    [acceptConnectionThread start];  
}
return self;
}

-(void) startAcceptingConnections {
self.clientSocket = accept(self.serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len);
NSLog(@"new socket response: %d", self.clientSocket);

}
@end
```

to establish the connection i'm calling setNetworkSocketStream:

```
- (void) setNetworkSocketStream:(CFStringRef) host withPortNumber:(UInt32) port; {
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, host, port, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];

outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream open]; 
}
```

and i have implemented handleEvent method from NSStreamDelegate.

when my view controller loads up, i init the server object and i have a button which calls setNetworkSocketStream:(CFStringRef)@"94.21.53.41" withPortNumber:(UInt32)21360

so i run it on the simulator and when i press the button which calls setNetworkSocketStream

i get responses like:
new socket response: 12,
stream event 1,
Stream opened,
stream event 1,
Stream opened,
stream event 4,
StreamEventHasSpaceAvailable,
stream event 2,

so i tried running it at the same time on my phone only without the server class init,
but when i call setNetworkSocketStream from there nothing happens

i thought that if there was a connection between the two i'll get some events from handleEvent, but nothing...

all this networking programming is very new to me so i probably made a lot of mistakes along the way.

after all that, my questions are if anyone can point me to why i can't establish the connection?, is my code even remotely close to establish a succeful connection?, is it even possible to test this scenario with both the simulator and the iphone?, really any suggestions, advice or pointers will be very helpful.

much thanks to anyone who read through the whole question and a thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help...

Comment: I didn't look at your code, kind of busy with other stuff. But my advice is since you are new to network programming stop trying it out with simulator and phone. 2nd if one is acting as Client and other one is gonna act as client then it's a client server architecture. In order to establish a P2P u need to do holepunching.  I have a build a p2p using boost asio network library which runs on mac windows ubuntu iphone and android. So it's possible to do only thing is try testing it out with PC's and then compile it to mobiles.

Comment: That way it's easier to test it out. If you are using it as client server then u should no that Server should have a public IP with the specific port open.

Comment: thanks for the advice i'll check the boost asio library and see if i can use it

Answer (score 1):

so i finally got the simulator and my phone to exchange messages

first, i stopped doing this:

```
tried running it at the same time on my phone only without the server class init, but when i call setNetworkSocketStream from there nothing happens
```

second, i was using :

```
NSString *response  = self.sendMessage.text;
NSLog(@"%@", response);
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response     dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

to send messages between the two, which for some reason didn't work so i switched the message sending method to the C send() function and that did it.